# RabbitMQ Management interface returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from request

Tags: docker, google-chrome, http, rabbitmq

I deployed a RabbitMQ container with docker. The docker command was `docker run -d -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --name rabbitmqcontainer rabbitmq:3.11-management`

After that when i send request to `http://localhost:15672` url that return `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

[image: Url]
[image: Response]

Note: i'm using latest versions of rabbitmq and erlang if it matters. And my management plugins are alerady enabled

The response from network of chrome explorer
[image: Network view]

I tried to take a look to rabbitmq managment UI but that request returned `EEP_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same issue (although deployed to minikube), the service is running, port is forwarded, but getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.